# Corda R3 DeployNodes command is failing for example cordapp

Tags: corda

I have downloaded the source code of example cordapp from [here](https://github.com/corda/cordapp-example).
I am getting following error when I give the command : 
`gradle deployNodes`.

Please guide me on what can be done.
Note: This is Corda V3.

```
> Task :java-source:deployNodes
Bootstrapping local network in C:\Blockchain\cordapp-example-release-V3\java-source\build\nodes
Node config files found in the root directory - generating node directories
Generating directory for Notary
Generating directory for PartyA
Generating directory for PartyB
Generating directory for PartyC
Nodes found in the following sub-directories: [Notary, PartyA, PartyB, PartyC]
Waiting for all nodes to generate their node-info files...
Distributing all node info-files to all nodes
Gathering notary identities


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':java-source:deployNodes'.
> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unknown constant pool tag [I@5d453b56 in classfile module-info.class (element size unknown, cannot continue reading class. Please report this on the FastClasspathScanner GitHub page.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 45s
5 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 3 up-to-date
```

Comment: Not facing the issue if i download the codebase from corda-v2 branch.

Comment: some issue with version corda_gradle_plugins_version = '3.0.9' plugin. facing the same issue, when tried migrating from V2 to V3.

Comment: What JVM are you using?

Comment: I am using JDK 1.8 Update java version "1.8.0_152"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-b16)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.152-b16, mixed mode).

Comment: Also faced the same issue on V2 to V3 migration. I had to downgrade Gradle from 4.5.1 to 4.4.1 in my project to get it working again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also faced the same issue on V2 to V3 migration. I had to downgrade Gradle from 4.5.1 to 4.1 in my project to get it working again.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/19170204)

Comment: Duly noted, modified my answer.

Comment: Ok, provided the above as comment.

Comment: Downgrading the gradle to version 4.4.1 works. Accepted the answer. Thanks @MatthieuMerlyn

Answer (score 0):

This is fixed in Corda 3.1. Upgrade notes here: https://docs.corda.net/upgrade-notes.html#v3-0-to-v3-1.